# Changing Logo image from CSS file?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have been trying to change the logo in this template where the logo is in inserted as a class from the css file but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code below. (P.S. Assume the new logo image name is NEWLOGO.jpg)

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    background:url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:90px 30px;
    width:90px;
    margin-left:-45px;
    height:30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working? When you change the CSS to point to a different image it doesn't load?

Comment: try to create demo to help you better

Comment: Beware of margin-left

Comment: Sorry, yes when I change the img src in he css file it doesnt't change instead it just shows the original image

Comment: It might be a caching issue - have you tried CTRL + SHIFT + F5? It's so called hard reload.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL + F5 keys to refresh without cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome. You can retry after disable cache.
Reference: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 0):

This very much sounds like a cache error.
[This article](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache) should help you disable the cache on multiple browsers.

Your browser is essentially loading an 'old' version of the page, which it has previously saved. This feature is used by browsers to try and increase navigation times, however sometimes when you are editing a site it does cause errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

your css file is probably cached by your browser.try clearing your browser history  to see the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo{
    background:url('../images/NEWLOGO.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    /*You need to replace the logo images in the same folder*/
    background-size:90px 30px;
    width:90px;
    margin-left:-45px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: This response would be even better if accompanied by a few words of explanation.